# What is the correct way to fetch promise data from a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, I was wondering about the correct way to get the data from a Promise.

I'm trying to get the values from the variable `fruits` but I'm getting [console.log() twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mlg5.png).

Here is an example of the data:

```
const fruits = [
  {
     id: '1',
     name: 'apple'
  },
  {
     id: '2',
     name: 'banana'
  }
]

const fruits$ = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, fruits))
```

Here is what I tried:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return ( 
      <p>Hello</p>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fruits$
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        data: response
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Is calling directly the variable and `.then()` the correct way? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the right way to do it, although you should also handle the possibility that the promise gets *rejected*. (Of course, your example can't get rejected, but presumably your example is a simplified version of something more complex.)

You're seeing two calls to `console.log` because there are two calls to `render`, because your component is first rendered with a blank `data` state property, then re-rendered when you update the `data` state property. The only way to avoid that is to not render the component at all until the data is available, by handling the promise in the component's parent and passing the data to this component via props.